# Create a multidimension list from a range of unique values

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a nxn 2D list where its values starts from 0 to n

something like this

> [ 1 2 3 4 ]
>
> [ 5 6 7 8 ]
>
> [ 9 10 11 12]

I tried to use the following code to do it

```
    self.board = [[list(range(n*n) for i in range(self.n)] for num in range(self.n)]
```

but instead it fills every element in the list with 16 elements

What expression should I use to replace list(range(n*n)) ?

Comment: `[list(itertools.islice(range(1,N+1),i,i+step)) for i in range(0,N,step)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
 >>> N = 4
 >>> board = [[j for j in xrange(N*i+1,N*i+N+1)] for i in xrange(N)]
 [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
>>> n = 4
>>> [[j*n+i+1 for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]
```